# Custom Seekbar preference thumb bug

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-seekbar

I create a custom SeekBar Preference for my app.
And I see it has a bug with thumb when clicking on preference.
See picture below:

[image: enter image description herretr e]

```
    <SeekBar android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@android:id/summary"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@android:id/widget_frame"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

Question is: how to fix the bug?

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: Question is: how to fix the bug?